# ffmpeg cannot open connection tcp://a.rtmp.youtube.com

Tags: ffmpeg, tcp, rtmp, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to live stream using ffmpeg, when live on Facebook it runs normally, but when I live on YouTube there is an error, is there anything wrong with the command I entered?  even though the command is the same as live on Facebook, but only the RTMP link has been changed

```html
ffmpeg -re -i out.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my-key-streaming"
```

and the output is

```html
ffmpeg version N-55112-g7eb9cf593e-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 61.100 / 56. 61.100
  libavcodec     58.114.100 / 58.114.100
  libavformat    58. 64.100 / 58. 64.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 91.100 /  7. 91.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2020-12-26T11:13:27.000000Z
    com.android.version: 10
  Duration: 00:00:03.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21344 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown), 1920x1080, 20225 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.99 fps, 30.01 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2020-12-26T11:13:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-26T11:13:27.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[tcp @ 0x58bf880] Connection to tcp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935 failed: Connection timed out
[rtmp @ 0x5893140] Cannot open connection tcp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my-key: Connection timed out
```

how to fix this, btw i use vps, sorry, my english so bad and this is the first time i asked on this website